# Lost in DB2 update statement

Tags: sql, db2, timestamp

I try to update a table using another table. I get the error number 407. It says that i try to insert a null in a notnullable column. 
I checked the column it my_TIMESTAMP column. Normally it can not be null. Because I update the colum,n with `current timestamp`. It should generate a timestamp. Where is the problem?

```
    UPDATE table1 mytable
    SET (
      my_PROCESS,
      my_TIMESTAMP,
      col3, 
      COL5
    ) = (
    SELECT
      (select PROCESSNAME from table3),
      current timestamp,
      COL3,
      COL5  
    FROM table2 mytable2
    WHERE mytable.COL4 = mytable2.COL4  
    )
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 'x'
        FROM table1 mytable1, table2 mytable21
        WHERE mytable1.COL4 = mytable21.COL4            
    );
```

Comment: What is the result of your inner `SELECT` statement. Does it contain any null values corresponding to any column in target table being Not Nullable.

Comment: @husbas The error points to `TBSPACEID=7, TABLEID=265, COLNO=2` `And it is the my_TIMESTAMP column.

Comment: strip the UPDATE-SET part from the statement and execute it, then take a look at the result and scan for "-". That one will produce the problem

Comment: please provide the create table1 and create table2

Comment: @peter-miehle Oleyyyy.. I got it.. First of all thanks for the help. It is really strange. The problem was at where exists part. I changed the part with where mytable.id IN (SELECT mytable1.id .....) . Then it worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replace the `where exists` condition with `where ... IN` changed the where condition.

```
 UPDATE table1 mytable
    SET (
      my_PROCESS,
      my_TIMESTAMP,
      col3, 
      COL5
    ) = (
    SELECT
      (select PROCESSNAME from table3),
      current timestamp,
      COL3,
      COL5  
    FROM table2 mytable2
    WHERE mytable.COL4 = mytable2.COL4  
    )
    WHERE mytable.id IN (
        SELECT mytable1.id
        FROM table1 mytable1, table2 mytable21
        WHERE mytable1.COL4 = mytable21.COL4            
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not trivial to answer due no access to the data. But did you try as workaround using MERGE INTO command like this? In this case you can check merged data by executing only statement in USING. Of course you can add predicate into this statement to make the row set shorter.

```
MERGE INTO TABLE1 AS T1
USING (SELECT T3.PROCESSNAME_1 AS MY_PROCESS, T2.COL3, T2.COL4, T3.COL5
FROM TABLE3 T3, TABLE2 T2) AS Q1
ON T1.COL4 = Q1.COL4
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET (MY_PROCESS, MY_TIMESTAMP, COL3, COL5) =
(Q1.MY_PROCESS, CURRENT TIMESTAMP, Q1.COL3, Q1.COL5)
```